# Unable to fit a text and image in a HTML table

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-email

I am trying to make a HTML email layout using table row, where text and image is being showed in one row. But I am not able to fit in[image]

This is what I want it to look like
[image]

My code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="padding">
      <table class="content3">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="padding: 20px; background-color: #f7f7f7;">
              Learn how to sync your smartwatch or a fitness band with the Vantage Fit app <a href="#">here</a>.
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="images/smart-devices.png" width="150px" style="background-color: #f7f7f7; display: inline;" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting a fixed height for each `<td>` element. The design could be achieved.
I have rearranged the code at codepen: https://codepen.io/samuvpd/pen/gOWbXRx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the **`<td>`** on the right adapts it's size to the width property you set to **150px**. You could try setting both **`<td>`** at **100% height** and then set the **`<tr>`** to the size you want.

Technically if you give the parent a size and tell the children to fill **100%** of it it should behave as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the `<p>` default margin, those 2 `<td>` are actually the same height but the background color doesn't apply to the margin so it looks smaller.

I would recommend removing that margin and making the `<td>` have the background color.

```css
td {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="padding">
      <table class="content3">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="padding: 20px; ">
              Learn how to sync your smartwatch or a fitness band with the
              Vantage Fit app <a href="#">here</a>.
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <img
              src="mages/smart-devices.png"
              width="150px"
              style="display: inline"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```